# What antivirus software goes along well with Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, anti-virus

I'm using McAffee antivirus on a windows 7 machine, and experience many problems with Thunderbird, at random times of the day. I read many blog posts, and took some steps to get a better experience, bug Thunderbird keeps hanging, and when it does, the `mcshield.exe` process takes most of my CPU. I'm considering switching to another product, but I would like to be sure it works well with Thunderbird before paying anything.

What antivirus do you use with Thunderbird, and do you experience problems ? What would you recommend ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use AVG AntiVirus Free Edition and Thunderbird for the last 5 years and never had any performance issues with that combination. You can try that, it costs no money and if you don't like it or don't feel save, just remove it.